# Rails 3, belongs_to, has one? For 3 models, Users, Instances, Books

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following models:
Users (id, name, email, instance_id, etc...)
Instances (id, domain name)
Books (id, name, user_id, instance_id)

In Rails 3, When a new book is created, I need the user_id, and instance_id to be populated based on the current_user.

Currently, user_id is being assigned when I create a new book but not instance_id? What needs to happen in rails to make that field get filled out on book creation?

Also, shouldn't rails be error'ing given that I can create books without that instance_id filled out?

thxs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have de-normalized `User` and `Book` models by adding reference to `Instance` model. You can avoid the redundant reference unless you have a specific reason.

I would rewrite your models as follows:

```
class Instance  < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  has_many :books, :through => :users, :order => "created_at DESC"
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :instance
  has_many   :books, :order => "created_at DESC"
end


class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_one    :instance, :through => :user
end
```

Now to create a new book for a user.

```
current_user.books.build(...)
```

To get a list of the books belonging to user's instance:

```
current_user.instance.books
```

To get a list of the books created by the user:

```
current_user.books
```

Make sure you index the `instance_id` column in `users` table and `user_id` column in `books` table.

Comment: I just tried your idea here. and instance_id is not being populated. In the dev log it's NULL

Comment: In the book controller, here is the command I'm using to create the record "@book = current_user.books.build(params[:book])" It's inserting NULL for instance_ID user_id is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Rails will only produce an error in this case if (a) you have a validation that's failing, or (b) you have database foreign keys that aren't being satisfied.

What's an instance? i.e. if instance_id is to be populated based on the current user, what attribute of the user should supply it? (the instance_id? why?)

Comment: Just saw your other question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663861/using-default-scope-in-a-model-to-filter-by-the-correct-instanceid.

Is instance a join model? i.e. you have a many-to-many relationship between users and books?

If so... the convention is to call it something like user_books - i.e. to _mean_ something - to describe what it is.

Comment: Instances are companies (like yammer). Users belong to instances. and when you create a book I need to record the instance_id and the user_id. InstanceID because a company should only see their records, user_id so I know who owns the note. Does that help?